# How to sort array for already existing names and add objects from those names to original name

Tags: arrays, powershell, comparison

I currently have an array in Powershell giving me a list of users with certain objects (info). There are multiple instances of certain users but with different info attached. I want to add that info so when I search for a certain element/name in array it comes back with all the info.

So say for example I have three array.name all equal to John. But each instance has different addresses. I want to add those different address together so I have one array.name equal to John but it has the three different address attached.

I have tried a loop within a loop and creating a new array by trying to compare what I already have with the new array. But it doesn't work and spews out an endless list.

```
$arr3 += $arr2[0]

For ($a=0; $a -le ($arr2.length - 1); $a++) {
    $temp3 = $arr2[$a].managedBy
    if ($temp3 -eq $null){
        $temp3 = "none"
    }
    For ($b=0; $b -le ($arr3.length - 1); $b++) {
        if ($temp3 -eq $arr3[$b].managedBy) {
            $arr3[$b].name += "`n"
            $arr3[$b].name += $arr2[$a].name
            $arr3[$b].description += "`n"
            $arr3[$b].description += $arr2[$a].description
            $arr3[$b].info += "`n"
            $arr3[$b].info += $arr2[$a].info
        } else {
            $arr3 += $arr2[$a]
        }
    }
}
```

I should have arr3 with a list of managedBy that don't repeat but with extra info attached in some cases. This doesn't work and ends up spewing out a huge endless array.

Comment: try using `Group-Object` to group by the name and then concatenate the addresses with `-join ';'` before you add them to the address property. ///// also, it may be easier to build a NEW object and send that to a NEW collection instead of trying to work on the old objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Lee_Daily's suggestions, you can do the following:

```
$arr3 = $arr2 | Group-Object ManagedBy |
   select @{n='ManagedBy';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Name';e={$_.group.Name -join ";"}},
   @{n='description';e={$_.group.description -join ";"}},
   @{n='info';e={$_.group.info -join ";"}}
```

This code groups names that are identical into one line of output using `Group-Object`. The `.Group` property contains the remaining properties of the $arr2 objects. All of the array object properties are stored in the `.group` property of the `Group-Object` output, hence the need to use nested properties (`$_.group.property`) to access them. I excluded `ManagedBy`. I use the `-join` operator to join all values of a single property with a semi-colon delimiter.

To customize this code for your situation, you can change the following since you may need to swap properties to reach your desired effect:

1. `Group-Object ManagedBy`: You can use another property besides ManagedBy. This should be the property that contains duplicate values across your array that you want to reduce to one entry.
2. `Select @{n=...;e={...}}`: The property you are grouping by (`ManagedBy` in this case) is mapped to the `.name` property of the `Group-Object` output. The remaining headers and values in the hash table should be the multiple values you want to join in one line. The hash table values should exclude the grouped property.
3. `-join ";"`: This is the delimiter that separates your common properties' values. Your info property value will be in the format `Info 1;Info 2;Info 3`. You can update this delimiter.

Comment: Yes, I see. I initially tested with different properties that had correct results. I edited on the fly and it broke things. I'll update. Having an object property in the data called Name did not help expose my flaw.

Comment: @LotPings, I believe I corrected all of the errors.

Comment: This works great, I'm pretty new to PS so still learning different cmdlts. How would I add .email address from arr2 without repeating it?

Comment: @Crasos if there is only one email `@{n='email';e={$_.group[0].email}}` otherwise try `@{n='email';e={($_.group.email|sort -unique) -join ";"}}`

Comment: @LotPings thankyou, -unique worked perfectly. I appreciate the fantastic help and explanations both of you have given.

Comment: @LotPings I'm just tidying up the output from the script just now and I'm wondering if it is possible to instead of join the groups together with a " ; " which creates a big lone line of info, if it's instead possible to have each item on its own line? I tried `n but it just includes it.

Comment: That is a formatting issue, you do work with objects inside a pipeline here, where is the output destined for? A csv file, a text/html report? With multiple columns extending over several lines this gets messed up soon.

Comment: @LotPings it is destined for an html report.

Comment: Then it might work with different join characters and a bit of CSS and the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet. But this is a totally **NEW** question.